# How to start a Chrome Extension (Livereload) with AppleScript?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, applescript, launch, livereload

I use the [Livereload Extension in Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/livereload/jnihajbhpnppcggbcgedagnkighmdlei). To make the extension work, I have to open Chrome and then click on the icon to make the extension refresh the tab when needed.

**How can I launch the extension with AppleScript?**

I came so far:

```
  on run {input, parameters}
    tell application "Google Chrome"
        open location "http://localhost:4000/"
    end tell
    return input
  end run
```

Comment: Please format your code properly. No \` needed, just 4 leading spaces on all lines.

Comment: Fixed it and reformatted.

Comment: I looked at the [source of the extension](https://github.com/livereload/livereload-extensions). It's probably best that you modify it and have your own version that does what you want - there is no way of getting the `browserAction.onClicked` event to fire besides clicking the button (or do fragile stuff like simulating a click). How to modify heavily depends on what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Hello Xan, Thank you for your help. Modifying the extension goes beyond what I can accomplish. I have to try another path. Maybe I try to make the mouse pointer ciick via x-y-coordinates to click on the extensions's start button. Thank you for helping me.

Comment: Wait, it really shouldn't be hard to modify the extension. All that matters is the logic you need behind it. You'll need to modify [this part](https://github.com/livereload/livereload-extensions/blob/master/src/chrome/global.coffee).

Comment: I think I will try something else. Livereload injects a javascript into the html. Maybe I just inject https://github.com/livereload/livereload-js into my HTML-websites. I have to think about the best solution. Altering an extension is really difficult and to time consuming for me.